# Kivy - ListAdapter background color

Tags: listview, background-color, kivy, listadapter

Simple problem:
I want to set the background color for my ListAdapter, cls = ListItemButton.
Whatever I do, it stays the same ugly green (and red on press). Of course i tried background_color, made a custom rule for ListItemButton, etc, nothing works ...

**kv code:**

```
ListView:
    adapter:
        ListAdapter(data=["1","2"], cls=ListItemButton)
```

nothing special in my py file.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to override the `selected_color` and `deselected_color` properties of the `ListItemButton`. The easiest way to do this is with a kv class rule, which will affect all instances of `ListItemButton`:

```
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
<ListItemButton>:
    selected_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
    deselected_color: 0, 0, 0, 1

ListView:
    adapter:
        ListAdapter(data=["1","2"], cls=ListItemButton)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my question! May I ask where you got that Info from? Didn't find it in the docs, or did i overlook something?

Comment: It's in the reference for `ListItemButton`: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html#kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton

Comment: @RyanP hey Thanks for the selected_color and deselected_color, but I have a question regarding when I click on the listitembutton it shows my selected color after showing the typical light blue kivy color, was wondering if you had the numbers for the normal light blue kivy color that is used in basically all their widgets, kind of like the toggle button colors.